# Plotting 2D data in matplotlib without imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, 2d, imshow

I want to plot some 2D data on a colormap, with pixels uniformly distributed over the coordinates X, Y (as would result from e.g. `np.meshgrid`). Is there a way to do this in `matplotlib` without `imshow()`?

Consider two 2D data fields Z and W, which have values defined for the coordinates X, Y. Let's say I want to plot W as a simple colormap with nearest-value interpolation, and to over-plot Z as a set of contours. I would expect there to be two functions to do this with **very similar calling signatures**, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.interp2d(X, Y, W)  # plots W with interpolation
ax.contour(X, Y, Z)   # plots Z contours
```

I am wondering if a function like the placeholder `interp2d` exists.

`imshow` cannot accept `X` and `Y`, and instead requires configuring `extent`, `origin`, etc. in way that I find cumbersome an unintuitive, and is less readable.

I don't mind if the function is from a library other than `matplotlib`, as long asit can interface with `matplotlib`'s axis objects.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `plt.pcolor`. I am overjoyed and will never use `imshow` again. This works just as I suggested in the question:

```
ax.imshow(X, Y, W)
```